Accessing iFrame Content using JavaScript
I have a website, abc.com, in which I load an iframe from a publisher, let's say hello.com. The content from hello.com is loaded in an iframe, I want to extract content of that iframe using JS. Is it possible? Is it possible to at least get the screenshot using JS?
The CORS on hello.com does not allow any other site to access content though. My assumption was as the content is loaded on client in an iframe, can we do something using JS?

javascript can not access cross origin iframes for obvious reasons - unless you have control of the iframe domain, there is almost absolutely nothing you can do about it - perhaps a "WebExtension" could help
